# Php file_exists does not work

Tags: php, file, path, exists

I want to check if a file in a directory exists.
I my case it does exist.

```
if(file_exists("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myApp\\img1.jpg"))
{
    echo "is file";
    exit;
}
```

Here is an image of that path:

[image]

But somehow this does not work.

Comment: windows wants *two* backspaces after the drive letter. and since you have to escape them, you have to write *four* backspaces after `C:`

Comment: "On windows, use //computername/share/filename or \\computername\share\filename to check files on network shares."

Comment: @kosta it's a local drive. not a network share

Comment: than this will work `if(file_exists("C://xampp/htdocs/myApp/img1.jpg"))`

Comment: You can also use forward slashes for paths.

Comment: If you are going to work with files, you might consider using an abstraction layer like [thephpleague\flysystem](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/api/). Then you don't need to worry about the environment you are running your application on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward slashes will also work on Windows. You can use forward slashes so you do not need to escape them:

```
if (file_exists("C:/xampp/htdocs/myApp/img1.jpg"))
{
    echo "file exists";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use only one `\` and follow bellow :

```
if(file_exists("C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\img1.jpg"))
{
    echo "is file";
    exit;
}
```

or

```
if(file_exists("img1.jpg"))
{
    echo "is file";
    exit;
}
```

because `img1.jpg` is your project root folder

Comment: can you explain your project folder/file structure?